# «Провозжаться» устаревшее слово или вообще жаргон?

Tags: значение-слов, жаргон, устаревшие-слова

Я так понимаю, что оно означает *провозиться.*

> Позади их слышен ропот:
>   «Нас на бабу променял,
>   Только ночь с ней **провозжался**,
>   Сам на утро бабой стал».

*песня «Из-за острова на стрежень»*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В песеном контексте слово имеет значение "состоял в связи" (порочной, вернее всего). Современное "провозился" здесь не может служить точным синонимом.

Упомянутое значение фиксирует вики как *просторечное*:

> прост., неодобр. побыть в дружбе или в каких-либо отношениях (обычно предосудительных, вызывающих осуждение) с кем-либо ◆ Позади их слышен ропот: // — Нас на бабу променял, // Только ночь с ней провожжался — // Сам наутро бабой стал! «Песня «Из-за острова на стрежень», стихи Д. Садовникова

К сожалению, более авторитетных источников привести пока не могу, но очевидно, что такое понимание куда более соответствует смыслу.

Проблема в другом. Классификация как "просторечного" вызывает вопросы. Сам песеный текст написан вполне литературным слогом и появление в нем, пусть и в прямой речи соответствующих персонажей, вызвало бы ощущение диссонанса.
так что, я полагаю, слово это на момент написания текста Садовникова имело не только самостоятельное значение, несколько отличное от "провозился", но и было достаточно широко распространено.

В литературе встречается еще и третье, восстанавливаемое по контексту значение "проторчать", "потратить время впустую". Тоже не сводится напрямую к основному. К сожалению, вообще нигде не фиксируется.

> - Дубина! - гаркнула я первым делом. - Ты тут вечность провожжаться решил?

Ципорина, "Власть над водами пресными и солеными".

И да, я за написание "прово**жж**ался". Но это отдельный разговор.

Comment: Спасибо большое! *И да, я за написание "провожжался"* — я тоже за такое написание и произношение, но, к моему удивлению, и Гуляев, и даже Шаляпин произносят и З тоже. Странно.

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно верно понимаете.
“>”Провозжаться, совр. Провозиться с кем-, чем-либо: "Целый  день провозжался с “>”ребятишками". 
Словарь народных говоров, РАН (https://iling.spb.ru/dictionaries/srng/32.pdf - стр. 100). Устаревшее, можно отнести к диалектизмам.

Comment: Это значение по смыслу не подходит: _возиться_ - значит уделять _много_ времени, а здесь акцентируется _малое_ его количество (только ночь = стоило _всего одну ночь_ с ней... и наутро он аж бабой стал). В словаре синонимов слова "вожжаться" есть _сюсюкаться, цацкаться, нянчиться, тетешкаться._